# AFNetworking 2.0 returning download temp location instead of the place it saved

Tags: ios, objective-c, download, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

This is my code:

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];
    NSString *URLForSend = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/pk/%ld/", [_downloadFileURLString stringByAppendingString:_userName], (long)pk ];
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:URLForSend];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
    __unsafe_unretained typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [manager downloadTaskWithRequest:request progress:nil destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response) {
        NSURL *downloadDirectoryPath = [self downloadAreaDirectoryURL];
        return [downloadDirectoryPath URLByAppendingPathComponent:[targetPath lastPathComponent]];
    } completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath, NSError *error) {

        NSString *relativeFilePathString = [filePath lastPathComponent];
        [weakSelf updateFilePathFromStack:relativeFilePathString withpk:pk];
        NSLog(@"File downloaded to: %@", filePath);

    }];
    return downloadTask;
```

I read the documentation a couple of times and Im left with 2 questions:

1. in the `destination` block where does it get `targetPath` from?
2. in the completion handler, the `filePath` leads me to the temp file, I want the name of the finally saved file.

I want it to be saved to the `downloadedAreaDirectoryURL`(a directory I opened in the cache folder) and for it to be `downloadedAreaDirectoryURL`/*fileNameLikeItsCalledFromServer*

Note that I don't know that file name before I actually get it, since I'm accessing it with the PK number from the DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The `AFURLSessionManager` uses the new `NSURLSession` class introduced in iOS 7.0. Specifically, it uses the `NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate` with the method [URLSession:downloadTask:didFinishDownloadingToURL:](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html), which sends it a file URL to a temporary file.
2. I just tried the same code that you've posted (with slight modifications to get the paths right) and I got the same returned URL from the `destination` block to the `filePath` parameter of the `completionHandler`. In addition, the file was successfully moved to my caches directory. I suggest you to add a listener for `AFURLSessionDownloadTaskDidFailToMoveFileNotification` to verify that the file move operation did not fail.

Comment: so in filePath in the completion handler you got the correct url to the moved file? not the temp? Maybe you're right, Ill check if the move is failing...

Comment: Yup, I've got the URL to the moved file.